# Move Constructor choosen instead of Copy. [reference to std]

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

Can anybody enlighten me where I can find

**prvalue**:

> When used as a function argument and when two overloads of the function are available, one taking rvalue reference parameter and the other taking lvalue reference to const parameter, an rvalue binds to the rvalue reference overload (thus, if both copy and move constructors are available, an rvalue argument invokes the move constructor, and likewise with copy and move assignment operators).

from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

in the [standard here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the final working draft (n4659) of the C++17 standard, it is found in [**`16.3.3 Best viable function [over.match.best]`**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.best) and specifically in the following subsection:

> **16.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences [`[over.ics.rank]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank)**
>
> 3 Two implicit conversion sequences of the same form are
>   indistinguishable conversion sequences unless one of the following
>   rules applies:
>
> (3.2) — Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion
>   sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if
>
> (3.2.1) — S1 is a
>   proper subsequence of S2 (comparing the conversion sequences in the
>   canonical form defined by 16.3.3.1.1, excluding any Lvalue
>   Transformation; the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a
>   subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence) or, if not that,
>
> (3.2.2) — the rank of S1 is better than the rank of S2, or S1 and S2
>   have the same rank and are distinguishable by the rules in the
>   paragraph below, or, if not that,
>
> [(3.2.3)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3.2.3) — S1 and S2 are reference
>   bindings (11.6.3) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter
>   of a non-static member function declared without a ref-qualifier, and
>   S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and S2 binds an lvalue
>   reference

I believe (3.2.3) applies to your case.

There are some relevant examples that follow:

> ```
> int i;
> int f1();
> int&& f2();
> int g(const int&);
> int g(const int&&);
> int j = g(i); // calls g(const int&)
> int k = g(f1()); // calls g(const int&&)
> int l = g(f2()); // calls g(const int&&)
> ```